# async version of UIViewPropertyAnimator addCompletion

Tags: ios, swift, swift-concurrency

UIViewPropertyAnimator has an `addCompletion` method that lets you provide a block of code to be executed when the animation ends:

```
func addCompletion(_ completion: @escaping (UIViewAnimatingPosition) -> Void)
```

When I try to use an animator in a Task and I call that method, I get a warning:

| Consider using asynchronous alternative function

Sure enough, there *is* an asynchronous alternative function:

```
func addCompletion() async -> UIViewAnimatingPosition
```

But I can't make any sense of this. Where's the *block* that is to be run when the animation completes? In fact, I find that if I call this method, any code that follows isn't even run. Is this just some massive bug in Apple's provision of async/await alternatives?

Here's an artificial example for use in a view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    Task {
        UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
            withDuration: 2,
            delay: 2,
            options: [],
            animations: {
                self.view.alpha = 0
            }
        ).addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            self?.view.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

You will see the warning on the `.addCompletion` line. How would you rewrite the code so that it still works (the view disappears and then reappears) but the warning goes away?

Comment: If you aren’t using the async/await version you don’t need Task it doesn’t serve a purpose.

Comment: I think the confusion arises because the function name hasn't changed, it has just been overloaded with a concurrent version; it is still called `addCompletion`, but as you note, there is no "completion" being added. A better name might be `completionPosition()` so then you would say `await  animator.completionPosition()` but I guess Apple wanted to keep the function names for concurrent versions

Comment: @loremipsum "artificial" I said. In real life there _is_ a reason to be using Task; else, I would not have encountered the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this just some massive bug in Apple's provision of async/await alternatives?

This is part of the [Objective-C interoperability for methods with completion handlers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md#asynchronous-completion-handler-methods):

> An Objective-C method that is potentially an asynchronous completion-handler method will be translated into an async method when it is either annotated explicitly with an appropriate swift_async attribute (described in the section on Objective-C attributes) or is implicitly inferred when the following heuristics successfully identify the completion handler parameter:

So, what you see is expected behaviour. Agreed, it looks really strange, you might've run in one of those not-so-nice corner cases, but it's just how the compiler translates by default the async-compatible Objective-C functions.

Anyhow, a workaround to get rid of the warning, and still keep the `Task`, is to wrap the animation within a `MainAction.run` call. The closure passed to to `MainAction.run` is non-async, so the warning will go away.

```swift
Task {
    await MainActor.run {
        UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
            withDuration: 2,
            delay: 2,
            options: [],
            animations: {
                self.view.alpha = 0
            }
        ).addCompletion { [weak self] _ in
            self?.view.alpha = 1
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a really nice workaround because I get to keep my existing code. It's also really weird!

Answer (score 2):

Just `await` the completion and set the alpha value back to 1

```
  Task {
        await UIViewPropertyAnimator.runningPropertyAnimator(
            withDuration: 2,
            delay: 2,
            options: [],
            animations: {
                self.view.alpha = 0
            }
        ).addCompletion()
        self.view.alpha = 1
    }
```

Comment: You can even keep the original "chained" version and just say `await UiViewPropertyAnimator(...).addCompletion()`

Comment: Weird. So now I can't say anything else in this Task, because everything I say is taken to be part of the completion. And I can't add more than one completion handler, which is possible with the non-async form. This is just nuts.